# Is XP divided among PCs or does each PC get the whole amount?

Tags: dnd-5e, experience-points

I'm confused about what exp to award my players after a battle.

The party fought 22 bandits in 7 waves, that makes 550 exp. The book is clear about how to calculate the XP for difficulty purposes and how to account for waves, that's not the question.

What I'm not sure of is how much each player gets after the battle. **Being a party of five do they get 110 XP each or 550 XP each?**